# VSCode: show entire variable in debug console

Tags: python, pandas, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

when debugging python code in VSCode, how do i show the entire variable.  As you can see from the image below, i am printing out the variable 'x'..but not all of it's values shows in the debugging console.  it is cut off and followed by an elipse indicating there is more:

[image]

While I know I can use the '>' to show a list of each item in the set in this case, is there a way to print the entire variable as a string in the debug pane/console - much like we would be able to if we were using the command line for our venv?

Answer (score 0):

```py
for item in set(x):
    print(item)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to click the `>` sign to the left of the variable result to expand it.

Comment: yeah..but then it's an entire list...and not as easy to copy that entire list.  would prefer it to be one long string that i can copy

Comment: in your question you said that you need to `show the entire variable` this button does exactly that, it shows you the entire list

Comment: i have updated it o be more clear.

Answer (score 0):

I made a simple replay. You can find the variable on the left side after using debug:

[image]

You can copy it like the following picture:

[image]

you can paste the copied content:
[image]

Comment: Does my solution solve your issue?

Comment: sorry for not responding. i appreciate the help.  but i knew about the left variable and copy..it is just simply not convenient/efficient i feel. - to many clicks..hence why i wasked about the debug tab/console.